# How to import webstorm code formatting settings into eclipse (Enide 2015)

Tags: webstorm, code-formatting, nodeclipse

Webstorm code formatting is very nice to see javascript code. 
I like to use same format settings in the Eclipse for node.js ([Enide](http://www.nodeclipse.org/enide/) 2015)
Is there any way to export webstorm formattings and import into Nodeclipse?

Webstorm formats code like this(I want to have this):

```
var passport = require('passport'), 
    GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google').Strategy;
```

Nodeclipse formats:

```
var passport = require('passport'), GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google').Strategy;
```